# Why call iframe from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to know why some ad codes or embed codes don't directly give you `iframe` code to embed on your site instead they give a JavaScript code which links to another JavaScript file on their server. The file on their server calls the `iframe` which serves the content. Why is this done and what are the benefits of this method.

Example: this is the code issued by Amazon:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.assoc-amazon.co.uk/s/ads.js"></script>
```

Which opens another JavaScript file that calls the `iframe`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest reason I can see for using a JavaScript file is that they want to be able to access cookies stored on the path of **your** page. They can't do that if they're supplying an iframe directly (they would only see cookies stored in the iframe's path). It's important; those third-party cookies relative to your page give them a lot of information, and let them store information specific to your visitor *and* your site, in your visitor's browser cookie database.

As for why Amazon gives you a JavaScript file that sets a few variables and then includes another JavaScript file, it gives them the ability to set the variables based on what they see (perhaps that `ads.js` is dynamically generated on the basis of what cookies it seems), and it lets them change the other JavaScript file path as they see fit.

Answer (score 1):

It is more flexible - if they decided to do something else later.

Also, JavaScript on your page has the freedom to parse the DOM and examine the content. An `iframe` on a different domain cannot access its parent.